# Share one tmp folder between main domain and subdomain in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have two domains, one is main domain and second one is subdomain. I need to share one tmp folder between both of them. In core.php i did like this `define('CACHE_DIR', TMP.'cache'.DS.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);` and `Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File', 'path' => ROOT.DS.'tmp'.DS));` , but its not working. Please if anybody knows about this issue, help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TMP constant will be defined to be within the app-directory of the subdomain so you'll end up saving the files whitin

```
/subdomain-path/app/tmp/cache/domainname
```

The TMP constant is defined inside bootstrap.php, but you can override it by defining it yourself inside your index.php

If you set the TMP to the right location, all temp, session and cache files will be written to that location. So consider it is a problem if session-data is stored in the shared directory

**important**

Be sure to set a different cache *$prefix* for each website. Otherwise Models cached for one website will also be used by the other website, **which may cause data from the wrong database to be used!!** This variable can be set inside your app/Config/core.php

**important2**

I would strongly advise you to **not** use the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` variable. If your website uses serverAliases (e.g. both handles *www.example.com* and *example.com*) then a separate cache-directory will be used for both (sub)domains. It's best to set a fixed path.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to set up a symbolic link from the subdomains tmp folder to the main domains tmp folder.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/172/create_a_symbolic_link_in_unix_solaris_linux/

Then the subdomain app can just treat the tmp folder as any normal app would.

There may be a special cake way to do it but this should work just as well :)